# Local Wikidata Instance contains data but returns no results

Tags: sparql, wikidata, blazegraph

I've been working extensively with Wikidata for about a year now and have installed a local Wikidata instance a handful of times as per the directions found in [the official mediaWiki article on Wikidata](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual#Standalone_service). I decided to install an instance afresh just recently and have encountered a puzzling problem. After running the `loadRestAPI.sh` command, the `wikidata.jnl` database was about 560G which is big but not as big as I expected it to be so I tried to query the database using a Python script and the `SPARQLWrapper` package but no query returned any results. Even the following query returned no results:

```
SELECT ?item WHERE {
  
  ?item ?prop ?val.
  
  } LIMIT 1
```

There were no errors, so the connection to the database was created, but still no results. If I change the name of the endpoint variable in my python script to a different host at my lab that is running an outdated Wikidata service, the query returns results. Clearly the issue is with this new, potentially incomplete instance.

How could my `wikidata.jnl` file contain 560G worth of data but not contain a single RDF-triple? This has never happened before to me.